# How to display a form in modal dialog on page load?

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, drupal-8

This is on Drupal 8.6, PHP 7.2, Theme is based on Bootstrap.

The scenario is, I want to display a dialog box with a subscription form in the home page. The dialog box will be loaded automatically when page load, not by click any link.
I see there are lot of examples there in the net, but all related to by clicking a link, modal will display. But I want to load it without any click.

I partially successful by using BootstrapDialog, but ajax is not working on form submit button. What I did, I attach a js file in the front page, with the code below. It shows the Modal Dialog box, and I tuned a page--newsletter--subscribe.html.twig, its working But submit button not working not ajax is working.

```
    BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Subscribe To Newsletter',
    message: jQuery('<div></div>').load('/newsletter/subscribe'),
    closable: false,
    draggable: true,
    closeByBackdrop: false,
    closeByKeyboard: false,
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialogRef){
            dialogRef.close();
        }
    }]
});
```

I saw there is an example in code node.preview.js file like this:

```
          var $previewDialog = $('<div>' + Drupal.theme('nodePreviewModal') + '</div>').appendTo('body');
      Drupal.dialog($previewDialog, {
        title: Drupal.t('Leave preview?'),
        buttons: [{
          text: Drupal.t('Cancel'),
          click: function click() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }, {
          text: Drupal.t('Leave preview'),
          click: function click() {
            window.top.location.href = event.target.href;
          }
        }]
      }).showModal();
```

But I never able to make it working in my custom module.

If some one can help on this, will be really great!

Update:
I just tried to put a link manually in the template and tried to open the dialog, but it gives me some error:

```
<a href="/newsletter/registration" class="use-ajax " data-dialog-type="modal">Show Dialog</a>
```

The error is as follows:

```
dialog.js?v=8.6.4:35 Uncaught TypeError: $element.dialog is not a function
at openDialog (dialog.js?v=8.6.4:35)
at Object.dialog.showModal (dialog.js?v=8.6.4:52)
at Drupal.AjaxCommands.openDialog (dialog.ajax.js?v=8.6.4:96)
at Drupal.Ajax.success (ajax.js?pkvhqx:155)
at Object.success (ajax.js?v=8.6.4:234)
at i (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)
at A (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4)
```

It seems some of the library is not loaded. Here is my global attachement:

```
  dependencies:
- core/jquery
- core/jquery.ui
- core/drupal.ajax
- core/drupal
- core/drupalSettings
- core/drupal.dialog
- core/drupal.dialog.ajax
- core/jquery.form
- core/jquery.once
- core/modernizr
```

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to the pro theme I have purchased named "glazed". Its removed the bootstrap modals library. When I disabled the Bootstrap Modal library from theme settings, Modals are working fine. But when I tried to enable the Bootstrap Modal, it gives the following message, which explain everything:

> **Your theme is trying to load the Bootstrap Modals override library from the bootstrap basetheme. This library is not compatible with Glazed Builder and therefore its assets have been removed from the page. To make this message disappear Please go to your (default) theme settings form, scroll down to Bootstrap settings, and under the Javascript category disable the "Bootstrap Modals" setting.**